# Правильна ли фраза пунктуационно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я сказал, что у всех, кто там сидит, нет личной жизни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> § 115. В придаточных частях сложноподчиненного предложения используются союзы и союзные слова (...), кто, (...), что, (...) и др. Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой.

Главная часть: `Я сказал.`

Придаточная к главной: `у всех нет личной жизни`, присоединяемая с помощью `что`. Требуется запятая: `Я сказал, что у всех нет личной жизни.`

Придаточная к придаточной: `там сидит`, присоединяемая с помощью `кто`.
Требуются две запятые: `у всех, кто там сидит, нет личной жизни`.

Всё вместе: `Я сказал, что у всех, кто там сидит, нет личной жизни.`

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.